# No sé usar un ArrayList específico para cada objeto

Tags: java, arraylist, objeto

Hola buenas estoy haciendo un programa en el que se puede ingresar empleados (que tienen de atributos el nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, sexo, fecha_inicio (la cual está en formato LocalDate) y titulacion) y luego especificar si son programadores o comerciales (que se añadirá de atributo un arraylist de lenguajes o de idiomas sea el caso), luego también tiene la opción de listarlos en la cual me encuentro con el error al imprimir los arraylist de comerciales o programadores ya que es como si cada objeto Programador usase el mismo y fuese global para todos los programadores al igual que en los comerciales y yo quiero que cada Comercial o Programador tenga su arraylist y se muestre como tal declaré sus clases, no compartir del resto.

La clase main Empresa2

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package empresa2;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.time.LocalDate;

/**
 *
 * @author pablo
 */
public class Empresa2 {

    public static ArrayList<Empleado> lista_empleados;
    public static ArrayList lista_lenguajes = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList lista_idiomas = new ArrayList();
    public static int n = 0;
    public static int pos_actual_programador = 0;
    public static int pos_actual_comercial = 0;
//    Al declarar como variable global el ArrayList lista_empleados no haría falta meterlo de parámetro en los demás métodos que la usen

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        
        lista_empleados = new ArrayList<>();

        do {
            switch (mostrarMenu()) {
                case 1:
                    ingresarEmpleado();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //ordenarEmpleados();
                    listarEmpleados();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
            }

        } while (mostrarMenu() != 3);   //TODO: Mejorar UX
    }

    public static void ingresarEmpleado() throws ParseException {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Reseteamos las variables
        String nombre, apellido1, apellido2, sexo;
        String fecha, titulacion;
        int edad;

        System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre: ");
        nombre = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca su primer apellido: ");
        apellido1 = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca su segundo apellido: ");
        apellido2 = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca su edad");
        edad = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduzca su sexo: ");
        sexo = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha en la que empezó a trabajar: ");
        fecha = entrada.nextLine();
        LocalDate fecha_inicio = LocalDate.parse(fecha);

        System.out.println("Introduzca su titulación (Inserte C para Comercial o P para programador): ");
        titulacion = entrada.nextLine();

        Empleado persona = null;
        switch (titulacion) {
            case "C": //TODO: Hacerlo case-insensitive
                persona = insertarComercial(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, sexo, titulacion, fecha_inicio);
                break;
            case "P":
                persona = insertarProgramador(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, sexo, titulacion, fecha_inicio);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opción no válida, seleccione C o P");
                break;
        }
        lista_empleados.add(persona);
    }

    public static int mostrarMenu() {
        int resp;

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("BIENVENIDO AL MENU\n"
                + "#############################################\n"
                + "A continuación tiene tres opciones:\n"
                + "1 - Ingresar un empleado\n"
                + "2 - Listar empleados\n"
                + "3 - Salir \n"
                + "Ingrese una opción: ");
        resp = entrada.nextInt();
        return resp;
    }

    public static void listarEmpleados() {
        //Ahora vamos a emplear un iterador para mostrar los empleados ya ordenados
        Iterator<Empleado> recorredor = lista_empleados.iterator();
        while (recorredor.hasNext()) {
            Empleado elemento_empleado = recorredor.next();
            System.out.println("#######################################"
                    + "Nombre: " + elemento_empleado.getNombre() + "\n"
                    + "Primer apellido: " + elemento_empleado.getApellido1() + "\n"
                    + "Segundo apellido: " + elemento_empleado.getApellido2() + "\n"
                    + "Edad: " + elemento_empleado.getEdad() + "\n"
                    + "Sexo: " + elemento_empleado.getSexo() + "\n"
                    + "Titulacion: " + elemento_empleado.getTitulacion() + "\n");

            String empl_titu = elemento_empleado.getTitulacion();
            
            //Tengo un problema y es que me salen siempre las mismas posiciones de ArrayList al imprimir
            System.out.println(empl_titu);
            if (empl_titu.equals("P")) {
                n=0;
                System.out.println("A continuación se muestran los lenguajes de programación aprendidos por el usuario: ");
                Iterator<String> idiomero = lista_lenguajes.iterator();
                while (idiomero.hasNext()) {
                    String prog_idioma = idiomero.next();
                    System.out.println(lista_lenguajes.get(n));
                    n++;
                }
            }
            if (empl_titu.equals("C")) {
                n=0;
                System.out.println("A continuación se muestran los idiomas aprendidos por el usuario: ");
                Iterator<String> idiomero = lista_idiomas.iterator();
                while (idiomero.hasNext()) {
                    String prog_idioma = idiomero.next();
                    System.out.println(lista_idiomas.get(n));
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Comercial insertarComercial(String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, int edad, String sexo, String titulacion, LocalDate fecha_inicio) {
        String idioma;

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca sus idiomas (presione 0 para salir): ");
            idioma = entrada.nextLine();
            if (idioma.equals("0")) {

            } else {
                lista_idiomas.add(idioma);
            }

        } while (!"0".equals(idioma));

        Comercial persona = new Comercial(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, sexo, titulacion, fecha_inicio, lista_idiomas);

        return persona;
    }

    public static Programador insertarProgramador(String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, int edad, String sexo, String titulacion, LocalDate fecha_inicio) {

        String idioma;

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca sus lenguajes (presione 0 para salir): ");
            idioma = entrada.nextLine();
            if (idioma.equals("0")) {

            } else {
                lista_lenguajes.add(idioma);
            }

        } while (!"0".equals(idioma));

        Programador persona = new Programador(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, sexo, titulacion, fecha_inicio, lista_lenguajes);
        return persona;
    }

//
    public static void ordenarEmpleados() {
//
//        Collections.sort(lista_empleados, new Comparator() {
//            
//            @Override
//            public int compare(Empleado persona1, Empleado persona2){
//                if (persona1.getApellido1().equals(persona2.getApellido1())) {
//                    return new Empleado(persona1.getApellido2().equals(persona2.getApellido2()));
//                }
//                
//                else {
//                    return new Empleado(persona1.getApellido1().equals(persona1.getApellido1()));
//                }
//               return; 
//            }
//       
//    }      
//}
    }
}
```

La clase Empleado

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package empresa2;

import java.time.LocalDate;
/**
 *
 * @author pablo
 */
public class Empleado {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido1;
    private String apellido2;
    private int edad;
    private String sexo;
    private String titulacion;
    private LocalDate fecha_inicio;

    public LocalDate getFecha_inicio() {
        return fecha_inicio;
    }

    public void setFecha_inicio(LocalDate fecha_inicio) {
        this.fecha_inicio = fecha_inicio;
    }
    
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    
    public void setNombre (String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public String getApellido1 () {
        return apellido1;
    }
    
    public void setApellido1 (String apellido1) {
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    }
    
    public String getApellido2 () {
        return apellido2;
    }
    
    public void setApellido2 (String apellido2){
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    }
    
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
    
    public void setEdad(int edad){
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    
    public String getSexo(){
        return sexo;
    }
    
    public void setSexo(String sexo){
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }
    
    public String getTitulacion() {
        return titulacion;
    }
    
    public void setTitulacion(String titulacion) {
        this.titulacion = titulacion;
    }
    
    public Empleado (String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, int edad, String sexo, String titulacion, LocalDate fecha_inicio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.titulacion = titulacion;
        this.fecha_inicio = fecha_inicio;
    }
}
```

La clase Comercial

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package empresa2;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.time.LocalDate;
/**
 *
 * @author pablo
 */
public class Comercial extends Empleado {
    public ArrayList<String> lista_idiomas = new ArrayList();
    
    public Comercial (String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, int edad, String sexo, String titulacion, LocalDate fecha_inicio, ArrayList lista_idiomas) {
        super(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, sexo, titulacion, fecha_inicio);
        this.lista_idiomas = lista_idiomas;
    }
}
```

La clase Programador

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package empresa2;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.time.LocalDate;
/**
 *
 * @author pablo
 */
public class Programador extends Empleado {
    public ArrayList<String> lista_lenguajes = new ArrayList ();

 
    public Programador (String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, int edad, String sexo, String titulacion, LocalDate fecha_inicio, ArrayList lista_lenguajes) {
        super(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, sexo, titulacion, fecha_inicio);
        //Programador.lista_lenguajes = new ArrayList<>();
        this.lista_lenguajes = lista_lenguajes;
    }
}
```

Y esta es la prueba del programa que como ven los Programadores comparten el mismo arraylist :/

```
BIENVENIDO AL MENU
#############################################
A continuación tiene tres opciones:
1 - Ingresar un empleado
2 - Listar empleados
3 - Salir 
Ingrese una opción: 
1
Introduzca su nombre: 
Ernesto
Introduzca su primer apellido: 
Juanes
Introduzca su segundo apellido: 
Juanes
Introduzca su edad
22
Introduzca su sexo: 
Introduzca la fecha en la que empezó a trabajar: 
2020-10-10
Introduzca su titulación (Inserte C para Comercial o P para programador): 
P
Introduzca sus lenguajes (presione 0 para salir): 
Java
Introduzca sus lenguajes (presione 0 para salir): 
Python
Introduzca sus lenguajes (presione 0 para salir): 
C
Introduzca sus lenguajes (presione 0 para salir): 
0
BIENVENIDO AL MENU
#############################################
A continuación tiene tres opciones:
1 - Ingresar un empleado
2 - Listar empleados
3 - Salir 
Ingrese una opción: 
1
BIENVENIDO AL MENU
#############################################
A continuación tiene tres opciones:
1 - Ingresar un empleado
2 - Listar empleados
3 - Salir 
Ingrese una opción: 
1
Introduzca su nombre: 
Sonia
Introduzca su primer apellido: 
Ramrez
Introduzca su segundo apellido: 
Huha
Introduzca su edad
22
Introduzca su sexo: 
Introduzca la fecha en la que empezó a trabajar: 
2020-10-10
Introduzca su titulación (Inserte C para Comercial o P para programador): 
C
Introduzca sus idiomas (presione 0 para salir): 
Ingles
Introduzca sus idiomas (presione 0 para salir): 
Frances
Introduzca sus idiomas (presione 0 para salir): 
Aleman
Introduzca sus idiomas (presione 0 para salir): 
0
BIENVENIDO AL MENU
#############################################
A continuación tiene tres opciones:
1 - Ingresar un empleado
2 - Listar empleados
3 - Salir 
Ingrese una opción: 
1
BIENVENIDO AL MENU
#############################################
A continuación tiene tres opciones:
1 - Ingresar un empleado
2 - Listar empleados
3 - Salir 
Ingrese una opción: 
1
Introduzca su nombre: 
Juan
Introduzca su primer apellido: 
MARIHUAN
Introduzca su segundo apellido: 
Oseee
Introduzca su edad
22
Introduzca su sexo: 
Introduzca la fecha en la que empezó a trabajar: 
2020-10-10
Introduzca su titulación (Inserte C para Comercial o P para programador): 
P
Introduzca sus lenguajes (presione 0 para salir): 
Cobol
Introduzca sus lenguajes (presione 0 para salir): 
pl1
Introduzca sus lenguajes (presione 0 para salir): 
0
BIENVENIDO AL MENU
#############################################
A continuación tiene tres opciones:
1 - Ingresar un empleado
2 - Listar empleados
3 - Salir 
Ingrese una opción: 
2
BIENVENIDO AL MENU
#############################################
A continuación tiene tres opciones:
1 - Ingresar un empleado
2 - Listar empleados
3 - Salir 
Ingrese una opción: 
2
#######################################Nombre: Ernesto
Primer apellido: Juanes
Segundo apellido: Juanes
Edad: 22
Sexo: 
Titulacion: P

P
A continuación se muestran los lenguajes de programación aprendidos por el usuario: 
Java
Python
C
Cobol
pl1
#######################################Nombre: Sonia
Primer apellido: Ramrez
Segundo apellido: Huha
Edad: 22
Sexo: 
Titulacion: C

C
A continuación se muestran los idiomas aprendidos por el usuario: 
Ingles
Frances
Aleman
#######################################Nombre: Juan
Primer apellido: MARIHUAN
Segundo apellido: Oseee
Edad: 22
Sexo: 
Titulacion: P

P
A continuación se muestran los lenguajes de programación aprendidos por el usuario: 
Java
Python
C
Cobol
pl1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver, tienes varios problemas en tu programa.

El primero, es que tu solo creas un arraylist en tu clase Empresa2 (uno para los idiomas de los comerciales, y uno para los programadores). En este arraylist, cada vez que añades un comercial por ejemplo, añades sus idiomas... O sea, tu añades el idioma español para el comercial1, luego añades ingles para el comercial2, y en tu arraylist tienes "español" e "ingles", porque no cambias de arraylist ni borras la entrada anterior.

Una solucion pasaría por, cuando vas a añadir el comercial por ejemplo:

```
  public static Comercial insertarComercial(String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, int edad, String sexo, String titulacion, LocalDate fecha_inicio) {
        String idioma;

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        lista_idiomas=new ArrayList();
        do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca sus idiomas (presione 0 para salir): ");
            idioma = entrada.nextLine();
            if (idioma.equals("0")) {

            } else {
                lista_idiomas.add(idioma);
            }

        } while (!"0".equals(idioma));

        Comercial persona = new Comercial(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, sexo, titulacion, fecha_inicio, lista_idiomas);

        return persona;
    }
```

De este modo, cada vez que vas a añadir un comercial creas un arraylist nuevo, único para la entrada en cuestión, y no uno general para todos.

Luego, el siguiente problema lo tienes cuando vas a imprimir el listado de tus empleados. Estas imprimiendo el arraylist de la clase Empresa2, y no el arraylist de la clase Comercial. Deberías de agregar un getter en la clase Comercial, para asi coger ese arraylist propio del empleado en cuestion y hacer un casting de tu elemnto Empleado a, por ejemplo, Comercial:

```
   if (empl_titu.equals("C")) {
                n = 0;
                Comercial c1=(Comercial)elemento_empleado;
                lista_idiomas=c1.getLista_idiomas();
                System.out.println("A continuación se muestran los idiomas aprendidos por el usuario: ");
                Iterator<String> idiomero = lista_idiomas.iterator();
                while (idiomero.hasNext()) {
                    String prog_idioma = idiomero.next();
                    System.out.println(lista_idiomas.get(n));
                    n++;
                }
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora ya me funciona bien el programa y ya me quedó bastante claro que donde fallaba era en que no hacía un casting de elemento_empleado a Programador o Comercial según fuese el caso y luego hacer un getter tanto de la lista de idiomas como de lenguajes... pero vamos ya va y gracias que también resumí los otros datos de los empleados con un toString para no meter toda la lógica en la clase main y así que sea todo más OOP, saludos!

Comment: Si, había un par de cambios extra que podías realizar para que quedase más "bonito" pero tampoco quise meterme ahí :D. Entre otras cosas, también te recomendaría que hagas control de entrada en la fecha para que no te tire error el programa por una fecha mal ingresada, sino que te la vuelva  a pedir, por ejemplo. Un saludo!

Answer (score -2):

Porque estás guardando en el mismo arraylist todo el rato tanto personas ya sean de tipo comercial o de tipo programador. Trata de hacer un arraylist de arrays que sean de tipo objeto ya sea Comercial o Programador